# Opening new activity from menu

Tags: java, android, menu, android-activity

I'm writing app for android and I have some problems.
I have main activity and settings activity.
I want to start settings activity from main activity menu.
I have this code to do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_preferences:
        Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(j);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But it isn't working. When i'm trying it i have logcat:

```
Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40a254c8
```

And settings activity isn't showing. I don't know what to do...

Comment: Seems you are in SettingsActivity

Comment: google for the error before posting it

Comment: The problem is that i'm in main activity. I changed code, like this in answers and it's not working. I checked with starting activity from button click. It works, but code is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this line

```
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

with this one

```
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add SettingsActivity in your manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="yourmainpackagename.SettingsActivity " />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Declare SettingsActivity in manifest. also use MainActivity.this instead of getApplicationContext().
this should help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you shouldn't use getApplicationContext as context. It should be like this:

```
    Intent j = new Intent(Firstclass.this, Secondclass.class);
    startActivity(j);
```

Don't forget to declare the Activity in your manifest and return true at the end. Hope this helps